# PHP header redirect with nested folders

Tags: php

I have a nested folder structure and I want to do a header redirect to login.php from every page that is not authorized. (Every page will include security.php)

NOTE: This whole folder could be in a subfolder so doing DOMAIN + login.php won't work.

Example:

```
-index.php
-login.php
-security.php
-people.php
-activities
     - view.php <-- How can I have do a header redirect back to login.php from here
```

security.php

```
if (!isAllowed())
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

index.php

```
require_once('security.php') // Works fine
```

activities/view.php

```
require_once ('../security.php'); //Works fine, but the HEADER redirect doesn't work
```

Comment: My question was not clear so I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

activities/view.php ->

```
require_once ('../security.php');
```

the `../` indicates that you move a folder back.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things you can do. I'd recommend setting a constant to define the current path and then use that to create an absolute link. You could also use server header data to figure out your current path and decide what the destination is based on that. Also, in php5+ use

```
require_once 'security.php';
```

Instead of ()

Answer (score 0):

Updated this post according to the asker's update:

`header('Location: /login.php');` should work.

Comment: That will work if the application was installed at the root of the domain, but for some reason they decided to put it in a subfolder.

Comment: Then define your subfolder and use `header('Location: /' . $subfolder . '/login.php');`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, by far the best approach is to define a useful [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) for the application.

In `php.ini`, we'd set our path like so:

```
include_path = ".:/path/to/webroot/your_app/includes"
```

...and then, in our application, include any contents of that directory with a simple `include 'file.php';`. This abstracts all that ugly path stuff out of our application and leaves the logic clean. We can also make it easy to reuse code across applications:

```
include_path = ".:/path/to/webroot/your_app/includes:/path/to/shared/includes"
```

If you do not have access to your `php.ini`, you can use PHP's [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function. This approach also improves portability.